# XAML Custom Control - Color Property Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a fairly simple custom control written in XAML but I'm having some trouble writing some dependency properties so the color can be changed.

Here is the bit of the control we're interested in.

```
<Viewbox>
  <Path Name="shape" Fill="Gray" Data="abc"/>
</Viewbox>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="shape" Property="Fill" Value="Gold" />
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

What I want to achieve is to replace the Fill's here (Gray and Gold) to something I can change as an attribute where I use the control.

So I could end up with this

```
<MyControl BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="Red" />
```

I have tried a few different videos including the MVA one but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I've tried this dependency property.

```
 public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(StarRatingControl), new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromRgb(0,0,0)));
```

and then using

```
Fill="{TemplateBinding BackgroundColor}"
```

But I just get the following errors:

"Cannot find the static member 'BackgroundColorProperty' on the type 'ToggleButton'."

and

"The member "BackgroundColor" is not recognized or is not accessible."

Both of these are in the XAML file, not the CS file.

Please can someone help / explain where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Please provide some more code. I can imagine whats not working, but it would outcome as a guess

Comment: As a note, the property type should be Brush, not Color.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page or user control has a name, for demo im using pageRoot.

then bind to the property using the following code.

```
Fill="{Binding BackgroundColor, ElementName=pageRoot"}
```

This should find the dependency property for you.

Comment: Alternatively, write `Fill="{Binding BackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I've got it to work using a combination of your advice.

So the  has a new Fill of:

```
Fill="{Binding StarBackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

and the dependency property is now of type Brush.

Thanks everyone! :)